# .htaccess 500 internal error(exclude directory)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just want to mention that I've checked out a couple results from the search from my title but not found a solution yet.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride All
RewriteRule ^(member)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule /^([^/]*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

I want mydomain.com/anything to show index.php?=u=anything, except if anything is  "member", then it should function like there's nothing in the .htaccess file. I have a member folder without any rewrite rules.
With or without line 2 and 3 it still gives me the error.

Error:ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

thanks

Comment: Try the last rule without the initial slashes: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?u=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

You have few errors here:

1. `AllowOverride` is not allowed in .htaccess
2. `RewriteRule` has `/` before anchor `^`
3. Without safeguard of `RewriteCond` your last rule will loop infinitely.

Try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(member)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```